# Не могу словить клик на элементе в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

По-идее в массив elements должны пушиться координаты квадрата и потом по клику сравниваться координаты чтоб узнать произошел ли клик на квадрате и после увеличить счёт и убрать квадрат.
Подскажите где я допустил ошибку ну или какой-то более изящный вариант.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var start = document.getElementById('start');
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
  var score = document.getElementById('score');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var choosenPos = getSquare();
  var choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
  var currentPos = 0;
  var stoping = null;
  var canvasLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
  var canvasTop = canvas.offsetTop;
  var elements = [];
  var points = 0;

  function getSquare() {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (640 - 1) + 1);
    return pos;
  }


  function getSpeed() {
    var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    return speed/20;
  }


  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
  }


  function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    ctx.fillRect(choosenPos, currentPos, 20, 20);
    elements.push({
      left: this.choosenPos,
      top: this.currentPos,
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    });
    currentPos += choosenSpeed;
    if (currentPos >= canvas.height) {
      currentPos = 0;
      choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
      choosenPos = getSquare();
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
      elements = [];
    }
    stoping = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  start.addEventListener('click', animate);

  stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(stoping);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - canvasLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - canvasTop;
    console.log(x, y);
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
      //console.log(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
      if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height &&
        x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
        points++;
        console.log('hi'); //чтоб узнать что клик сработал
        score.innerHTML = points;

      }
    });
  }, false);


};
```

```css
canvas {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start"> Start </button>
  <button id="stop"> Stop </button>
  <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
</div>
<canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения за мои правки вопроса.

```
elements.push({
  left: /*this.*/choosenPos,
  top: /*this.*/currentPos,
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});
```

Вы на каждую отрисовку добавляете в массив новый элемент. Наверное, это не то, что Вы хотели сделать.

Comment: Да получается не совсем то что надо. Где бы Вы посоветовали разместить добавление элемента?

Comment: @Mike Думаю - там, где вычисляются новые свойства квадрата. Зачем нужен массив элементов? Может быть, хранить ссылку на текущий квадрат (элемент) и обновлять его вертикальную координату во время движения?